# Cut string for-to specific character on PHP

Tags: php, string, substring

I have this string:

```
"$subtituloSlider = '#DD1624'"
```

I want to cut it for obtain this (i.e):

```
'#DD1624'
```

Exists any way to cut a string from determinate character (like '=') to determinate character (like ') ?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to learn about [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Simple way use `explode` and fetch the second match

Comment: `echo trim(explode('=',$string)[1]);`

Comment: thanks everybody! in twig is possible? not explode, slice from right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Explode**

```
$arr = explode('=', $String);
echo trim($arr[1]);
```